# How to resolve "_tkinter.TclError: unknown option"?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, menu

I am learning python tkinter but I have an error whenever I tried to compile it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/ 
widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile 
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "/home/jason/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 14, in <module>
menu.config(menu=menu)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1274, 
inconfigure
return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1265, 
in _configure
self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu").
```

My code is:

```
from tkinter import *

def hello():
    print "hello"    

root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
menu.config(menu=menu)
menu.add_command(label ="new",command = hello)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your code a little bit. Instead of `menu.config`, use `root.config`, you will not get any such errors.

For more information and detailed tutorial, kindly visit [Tkinter Menu Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm).